# Applescript - how to open

Tags: applescript

I'm very new to Applescript and I wrote a quick script that opens some files/directories based on their file kind and modification date. I need to open these files in iBooks after any modification. Can you please tell me if there's anything wrong with my script?

Here's the script:

```
set theFolder to alias "Macintosh HD:::"
tell application "iBooks"
open (file of theFolder whose name extension is "epub" and modification date is less than (current date))
end tell
```

Comment: Do you mean iBooks Author? iBooks is for iOS, and so is not an application for OSX. That's the first thing...

Comment: @CRGreen iBooks is included in OS X 10.9

Comment: @DigiMonk Although I still don't think it is scriptable.

Comment: @adayzdone true, iBooks.app on OS X 10.9 has no scripting dictionary .

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do it:

```
set theFolder to POSIX file "/Users/USER/Desktop/test_folder"
set theFolder to theFolder as alias
tell application "Finder"
    open theFolder
    set myList to (every file of theFolder whose modification date is less than (current date))
    set theApp to path to application "iBooks"
    repeat with myFile in myList
        open myFile using theApp
    end repeat
end tell
```

Because iBooks isn't scriptable, I tell Finder to use iBooks to open the file. I had some trouble when opening all files simultaneously. It should be possible, but I decided to use a repeat loop. In this example, it is assumed that all files are in folder test_folder on the user's desktop.